# Reactjs- How to fix after posting a new note via axios to the server, the render displays nothing?

Tags: reactjs

I am learning to alter data in the backend, json server. The data gets posted if I refresh the server but the render of the new list disappears from the screen after the submit button. Why did the displaying of the notes stop after I submitted a new note ?

```
const Note = ({note, toggleImportance}) => {
    const label = note.important ? 'make not important' : 'make important'
    return(
        <li >
            {note.content}
            <button onClick = {toggleImportance}>{label}</button>
        </li>
    )
}

export default Note


const App = () =>{
  const [notes,setNotes] = useState([])
  const [newNote, setNewNote] = useState('')
  const [showAll, setShowAll] = useState(true)

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('effect')
    axios
      .get('http://localhost:3002/notes')
      .then(response => {
        console.log('promise fulfilled')
        setNotes(response.data)
      })
  },[])
  console.log('render', notes.length, 'notes')

  const toggleImportanceOf = id => {
    const url = `http://localhost:3002/notes/${id}`
    const note = notes.find(n => n.id === id)
    const changedNote = {...note, important : !note.important}

    axios
    .put(url,changedNote)
    .then(response => {
      setNotes(notes.map(note => note.id !== id ? note : response.data))
    })
  }




  const addNote =(event) =>{
    event.preventDefault()
    const newObject = {
      content: newNote,
      date: new Date().toISOString(),
      important: Math.random() > 0.5
    }

    axios
    .post('http://localhost:3002/notes', newObject)
    .then(response => {
      setNotes(notes.concat(response.data))
      setNewNote('')
    })
  }

  const handleNoteChange = (event) => {
    setNewNote(event.target.value)
  }

  const notesToShow = showAll ? notes : notes.filter(note => note.important)


  const rows = () => {
    notesToShow.map(note => 
    <Note
      key={note.id}
      note={note}
      toggleImportance = {() => toggleImportanceOf(note.id)}  
    />)
  }


  return(
    <div>
      <h1>Notes</h1>
      <div>
        <button onClick = {() => setShowAll(!showAll)}>
          show{showAll ? ' important' : ' all'}
         </button>    
      </div>
      <ul>
        {rows()}
      </ul>
      <form onSubmit={addNote}>
        <input value={newNote} onChange={handleNoteChange}/>
        <button type="submit">save</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  )
  }

export default App;
```

How do I  fix this ? I want the new notes list to appeaar on the screen but it doesn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to enclose `<Note />` in the `rows()` function with `return()`

Comment: You can accept your own answer, so the question won't show up in the list of unanswered questions.